# How to write a unit test using Pytest for the main function in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, program-entry-point

I am new with unit testing and am confused about a lot of things. In the project I have been inherited, there is a `__main__.py` file, in which there is only one function:

```
import some_class

def func1 (some_instance) -> bool:
    #some code
    #returns true or False



some_instance = some_class()
func1 (some_instance)
```

Now, in another file (`tests.py`), which is in the same folder as `__main__.py`, I want to write a unit test to test the `func1` function. I don't know how I can do that. This is all I got:

```
import some_class
from __main__ import func1

def test_func1():
    test_instance = some_class()
    assert func1(test_instance) is True
```

It doesn't work and I think the `test_func1()` cannot even access `func1`. How can import `func1`? How can I test it? The (`from __main__ import func1`) part looks strange.

Comment: What does “doesn’t work” mean?  Do you get an error?  If so, include it in your question.  If you get no error, then either you’re not running the test at all, or it’s working just fine.

Comment: [`__main__` is a special name in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html). Specifically, when running the tests, `__main__` will refer to the `pytest` executable, so you can't import anything from it. General advice: don't put more stuff in `__main__.py` than it's necessary to run the program. Move all the logic to a separate module, e.g. `utils.py` and test that instead. Or move your `__main__.py` to a package to make it importable via e.g. `from myapp.__main__ import func1`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you want to test `Calculator` class and it's method `add`

```
# src/calculator.py

def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Then create a `test_calculator.py` file in the same folder as calculator.py -

```
# src/test_calculator.py

from calculator import add


def test_calculator_addition():
    output = add(2, 2)
    assert output == 4
```

That's it. Now you just type `pytest .` in your terminal and you should see something as follows -

```
test_calculator.py .                [100%]
===== 1 passed in 0.01s =======
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Prachant. The problem I'm having is, the func1 function I want to test is not a method inside a class. It's just a function. How can I test that?